# Struts 2 checkboxlist tag not saving

Tags: validation, struts2, checkboxlist

My checkboxlist is rendering correctly but gives a validation error "Invalid field value for field" on form post. I'm using Struts 2.5.26 with the struts2-cdi-plugin.

```
public class PersonAction extends MenuAction implements Preparable {
 
    private List<Person> personList;

    private Person person;
```

```
@Entity 
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<MemberType> memberTypes ;
```

```
@Entity 
public class MemberType implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String memberDescription;
```

```
@Named 
@SessionScoped 
public class ViewService implements Serializable {

    private List<Branch> branchList;
    private List<Diagnosis> diagnosisList;
    private List<MemberType> memberTypeList;

    @Inject
    private PersistenceService persistenceService;

    public List<MemberType> getMemberTypes() {
```

The jsp is probably where I am going wrong. As I said, it renders correctly in the view but gives the validation error for "value". I've tried many values here without success.

```
<s:checkboxlist listKey="id" listValue="memberDescription" list="viewService.memberTypes" name="person.memberTypes"/>
```

Comment: What is the value of the error? Where do you do validation?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I managed to get it to work like this: `<s:checkboxlist  label="label.membertype"
                                           list="viewService.memberTypes"
                                           listKey="id"
                                           listValue="memberDescription"
                                           name="memberIds"
value="person.memberTypes.{id}"  />` the name attribute has to be a List<Integer> and defined in the Action. Not sure if there's a better way? I still need to set person.memberTypes explicitly.

Comment: Did you resolve validation error "Invalid field value for field" ?

Comment: yes I did. It was for the name value, obvious now that I know. It should have been name="membersIds".

Comment: I couldn't guess how validation is performed in your code. Without relevant code is impossible to answer.

Comment: No problem, I should have given more detail.

Comment: The details should include the validation config.